How LaunchedEffect works
I don't really understand how LauchedEffect works, can you explain to me?
Here is the context, I make a account.get() call to find out if a user session exist or not in my app, depending on the case I return userExist = true or = false
But in all cases it returns me a return = true to know that I must launch my LaunchedEffect at that moment, here is my code
SplashUiState:
data class SplashUiState(
  val result: Boolean = false,
  val userExist: Boolean = false,
  val error: List<Pair<String, String>> = emptyList()
)

SplashViewModel:
private val _state = MutableStateFlow(SplashUiState())
val state = _state.asStateFlow()

...

init {
  delay(2000)
  checkSessionExist()
}

...

private suspend fun checkSessionExist() {
    when(val account = repository.getAccount()) {
        is ResponseResult.Error -> {
            Log.d("SplashViewModel", "${account.code}" + " ${account.message}")
            _state.update { it.copy(result = true, userExist = false,
                userError = listOf(
                    "code" to "${account.code}",
                    "message" to "${account.message}"
                )
            ) }
        }

        is ResponseResult.Success -> {
            Log.d("SplashViewModel", "${account.data}")
            _state.update { it.copy(result = true, userExist = true) }
        }
    }
}

SplashScreen:
val state by viewModel.state.collectAsState()

LaunchedEffect(key1 = state.result) {
  if (state.userExist) {
    Log.d("LaunchedEffect", "user exist")
    navController.navigate(AppRoutes.OVIDE_SCREEN) {
      popUpTo(AppRoutes.SPLASH_SCREEN) {
        inclusive = true
      }
    }
  } else {
    Log.d("LaunchedEffect", "user not exist")
    navController.navigate(AppRoutes.WELCOME_SCREEN) {
      popUpTo(AppRoutes.SPLASH_SCREEN) {
        inclusive = true
      }
    }
  }
}

My code seems good to me, well structured but when the user exists userExist = true it launches my code in the else and not in my if
How is this done?

@BenjyTec Of course :)

The code line
LaunchedEffect(key1 = state.result) {}

means that the code within the LaunchedEffect will be executed

one time initially
and then whenever the value of state.result changes.

It does not mean that the LaunchedEffect will only be executed once the state.result value is true. So your app will immediately go to the WELCOME_SCREEN before it even finished checking whether the session exists.
Please try to change your code like this:
LaunchedEffect(key1 = state.result) {
    if (state.result) {
        if (state.userExist) {
            Log.d("LaunchedEffect", "user exist")
            navController.navigate(AppRoutes.OVIDE_SCREEN) {
                popUpTo(AppRoutes.SPLASH_SCREEN) { inclusive = true }
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("LaunchedEffect", "user not exist")
            navController.navigate(AppRoutes.WELCOME_SCREEN) {
                popUpTo(AppRoutes.SPLASH_SCREEN) { inclusive = true }
            }
        }
    }
}

This will make the navigation happen once loading is finished.

"It does not mean that the LaunchedEffect will only be executed once the state.result value is true", Yes, that was how I saw it, thank you!

LaunchedEffect is remember used for remembering and forgetting lambda block with RememberObserver and coroutineScope under the hood.
@Composable
@NonRestartableComposable
@OptIn(InternalComposeApi::class)
fun LaunchedEffect(
    key1: Any?,
    block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit
) {
    val applyContext = currentComposer.applyCoroutineContext
    remember(key1) { LaunchedEffectImpl(applyContext, block) }
}

RememberObserver interface is used in LaunchedEffect to check when a code block is remembered, this happens when the block remember enters composition, and forgotten when Composable or code block exits composition.
@Suppress("CallbackName")
interface RememberObserver {
    /**
     * Called when this object is successfully remembered by a composition. This method is called on
     * the composition's **apply thread.**
     */
    fun onRemembered()

    /**
     * Called when this object is forgotten by a composition. This method is called on the
     * composition's **apply thread.**
     */
    fun onForgotten()

    /**
     * Called when this object is returned by the callback to `remember` but is not successfully
     * remembered by a composition.
     */
    fun onAbandoned()
}

You can implement this interface yourself to create state or Composable to clean up or call a callback like DisposableEffect yourself as well. I saw some usages to dispose bitmaps in some codes.
And LaunchedEffect implementation use it to cancel job it creates as
internal class LaunchedEffectImpl(
    parentCoroutineContext: CoroutineContext,
    private val task: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit
) : RememberObserver {
    private val scope = CoroutineScope(parentCoroutineContext)
    private var job: Job? = null

    override fun onRemembered() {
        // This should never happen but is left here for safety
        job?.cancel("Old job was still running!")
        job = scope.launch(block = task)
    }

    override fun onForgotten() {
        job?.cancel(LeftCompositionCancellationException())
        job = null
    }

    override fun onAbandoned() {
        job?.cancel(LeftCompositionCancellationException())
        job = null
    }
}

Basically, LaunchedEffect checks composition lifecycle by implementing RememberObserver and calls suspending functions by using a CoroutineScope.
Since it's a remembered function it resets it's lambda or creates a new closre when keys are changed.
DisposableEffects also checks onForgotten too which differs from LaunchedEffect compose lifecyclewise.
private class DisposableEffectImpl(
    private val effect: DisposableEffectScope.() -> DisposableEffectResult
) : RememberObserver {
    private var onDispose: DisposableEffectResult? = null

    override fun onRemembered() {
        onDispose = InternalDisposableEffectScope.effect()
    }

    override fun onForgotten() {
        onDispose?.dispose()
        onDispose = null
    }

    override fun onAbandoned() {
        // Nothing to do as [onRemembered] was not called.
    }
}


It's really very interesting and enriching thank you very much, I'm going to look in more detail at what you shared

Peek preview into KDoc from LaunchedEffect:

When LaunchedEffect enters the composition it will launch block into the composition's CoroutineContext. The coroutine will be cancelled and re-launched when LaunchedEffect is recomposed with a different key1.

Your checkSessionExist() always creates a state.result == true.
And this may be the cause that your LaunchedEffect never enters the other state.
Try the following call LaunchedEffect(state) {}
And also insert the additional if-clause @BenjyTec already added.
In addition the following should work:
LaunchedEffect(state) {
    if (state.result) {
        if (state.userExist) {
            Log.d("LaunchedEffect", "user exist")
            navController.navigate(AppRoutes.OVIDE_SCREEN) {
                popUpTo(AppRoutes.SPLASH_SCREEN) { inclusive = true }
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("LaunchedEffect", "user not exist")
            navController.navigate(AppRoutes.WELCOME_SCREEN) {
                popUpTo(AppRoutes.SPLASH_SCREEN) { inclusive = true }
            }
        }
    }
}

